# Picking emoji fonts in Emacs?

Tags: fonts, linux, emojis

How to set the font used for emojis in Emacs?

More specifically, how do I set it to **Noto Monochrome Emoji Font**?

- https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/tree/main/fonts
- https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji

Comment: Works in my instance: Delete/uninstall all emoji fonts on the system and then place your desired emoji font in ~/.local/share/fonts/ and run fc-cache -f -v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the emacs-28 NEWS file (<kbd>C-u C-h N 28.1 RET</kbd>):

```
** Improved support for Emoji.
On capable systems, Emacs now correctly displays Emoji and Emoji
sequences by default, provided that a suitable font is available to
Emacs.  With a few exceptions, all of the Emoji sequences specified by
Unicode 14.0 are automatically composed and displayed as a single
colorful glyph.  This is achieved by changes in the Emacs font
configuration, and by additional character-composition rules for the
Emoji codepoints that follow from the Unicode-defined sequences.

If your system lacks a suitable font, we recommend to install "Noto
Color Emoji"; Emacs will use it automatically if it's installed.  If
you prefer to use another font for Emoji, customize your fontset like
this:

    (set-fontset-font t 'emoji
                      '("My New Emoji Font" . "iso10646-1") nil 'prepend)

The Emoji characters are now assigned to a special script, 'emoji', so
as to make it easier to customize fontsets for Emoji display, as in
the above example.  (Previously, the Emoji characters were assigned to
the 'symbol' script, together with other symbol and punctuation
characters.)
```

It looks like this is not in any of the manuals. Might be worth a `M-x report-emacs-bug` to get that fixed.